# Background image of div not fitting in screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

Here is my code.  I am trying to display background images in a div tag on user click of links. But my background image is not fitting to screen (Putting height and width in css as shown below is at least allowing me to display the whole image but it is going way out of the screen). If I remove the height and width property from css, then the image is not displayed at all.

html ->

```
<body>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('wrapper').className ='IT_Spend_2012'">IT Spend</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('wrapper').className ='IT_Spend_2012'">Assessments</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('wrapper').className ='IT_Spend_2012'">Information</a></li>    
<li><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('wrapper').className ='IT_Spend_2012'">2012</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('wrapper').className ='IT_Spend_2013'">2013</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('wrapper').className ='IT_Spend_2014'">2014</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="document.getElementById('wrapper').className ='IT_Spend_2015'">2015</a></li>
```

```
</div>
<div id="wrapper" class="IT_Spend_2012"'></div>
</body>
```

css->

```
#wrapper { background-repeat: no-repeat; width:1500px; height:1100px;}
.IT_Spend_2012 { background-image: url('./img/IT_Spend2012.jpg'); }
.IT_Spend_2013 { background-image: url('./img/IT_Spend2013.jpg'); }
.IT_Spend_2014 { background-image: url('./img/IT_Spend2014.jpg'); }
.IT_Spend_2015 { background-image: url('./img/IT_Spend2015.jpg'); }
```

Comment: background-position: top left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:auto; or you can manually give it a size. (I would)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried percents?

```
 #wrapper { background-repeat: no-repeat; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

height may get tricky here...

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I tried this but the image is not getting displayed at all when I do this. Also, how do I make it responsive. I am not able to make it fit to various screen resolutions and sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Background image is a background image, it is printed on element's background. The element itself is not resized by background.

What you can do is set the element's width&height to the background image's.
Also check these links: [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover), [CSS3 backgrounds](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp), [CSS3 background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

If you are going to use `background-size: cover` then keep in mind that your image will not be fully visible like in the "background-size" link above unless, the div you display it on, has the same width&height aspect ratio as the image.